# Are there any open source SAT solvers with UNSAT core extraction algorithm built in?

Tags: reference-request, satisfiability, sat-solvers

Just like the title says. I need to use a SAT solver on a series of CNF formulas but not only do I need an answer of the type satisfiable/unsatisfiable but also some subset of clauses whose conjunction is still unsatisfiable (the unsatisfiability core).

I have read somewhere that it is possible to hack the code of some SAT solver (like MiniSAT) to produce UNSAT core, but I don't feel competent enough to actually do it. I was hoping that somebody else have already done it and have uploaded the code somewhere, but either that is not the case or I suck at Googling.

Comment: Tool requests are offtopic on [cs.SE].

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ , http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/160917

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software recommendations now live on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MUSer2](http://logos.ucd.ie/wiki/doku.php?id=muser) is probably *the* tool for extracting minimal unsatisfiable cores (MUS) currently. It treats the SAT solver as a black box, so you can plug in any solver you want.

If you want a solver with MUS extraction capability, [the newest version of PicoSAT](http://fmv.jku.at/picosat/) comes with a utility tool PicoMUS that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

For the Java world: [Sat4j](http://www.sat4j.org/) also has a MUS extraction tool, buried in the `org.sat4j.tools` package.

```java
AllMUSes musFinder = new AllMUSes(SolverFactory.instance());
ISolver solver = musFinder.getSolverInstance();

// add clauses to solver . . .

List<IVecInt> muses = musFinder.computeAllMUSes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Minisat and Z3 have the same hack to extract unsat cores. I found the Z3 example easy to understand. The link is here:

https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp

There are about 4 examples on extracting unsat cores. You can use the code as is by modifying the assertions, if you like C++.